# jsonl-to-conll conversion tool application error

Tags: jsonlines, conll

I need to convert a jsonl file to conll and i found this tool https://pypi.org/project/jsonl-to-conll/
but there is no examples or detailed documentation

i tried this command line on command prompt

```
C:\Users\Downloads>jsonl-to-conll certain_approved.jsonl output.conll
```

but it prints

```
'jsonl-to-conll' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

i added the jsonl-to-conll to variables enviroment  but i still have the same error
[image]
so i'm wondering am i using it in the right way or what ?
if there is another tool or script that can do the job please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guess you need to install the package or need to put it in PAtH otherwise you can't run it with the CMD command

Comment: I already done that, i just added a screenshot in the question now